# Update a List's object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to assign an object in a list using Linq, but I can't find how to do it.
I tried this:

`Items.Where(i => i.Code == line.Code).Single() = line;`

But it seems I simply cannot give the statement an object.
I can modify properties of those objects (Like this) :

```
Items.Where(i => i.Code == line.Code).Single().name = line.name;
```

But giving it the full item doesn't seem to be accepted.
Is there a reason to prevent this / a way to assign my value to the compatible item ?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot replace the value in the list using LINQ, because LINQ is a projection of a collection.

You can get your item and then find it in the list using `IndexOf`:

```
var item = Items.Single(i => i.Code == line.Code);
int index = Items.IndexOf(item);
Items[index] = new Item(); // replace the value
```

However, this approach is far from optimal in terms of algorithmic complexity, because it has to read through your list multiple times.
You can try to read more on [Dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-dictionary-class/) to find, add or replace items by key (in your case, `Code`) efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN Documentation: [Language Integrated Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/)

> By using query syntax, you can perform filtering, ordering, and
>   grouping operations on data sources with a minimum of code.

**You can not perform assignment using LINQ**, you need to use index to update particular record from the list

To update record you can try [FindIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.8)

```
int index = Items.FindIndex(x => x.Code == line.Code); //returns -1 if record not found
Items[index]?.Name = "Stackoverflow";
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the `Single` method returns. It returns a reference to the object that much the predicate you pass in the `Where` method. Specifically, when there is only one item in the `Items` that pass the predicate in the `Where` method, you will get a reference to this object. If there are more than one items, you will get an exception and if there are no items you will get null. Let's think about the happy case, in which you will have only one item. In that case, essentially you try to assign to this reference a new object. This does not make any sense. On the other hand that you try afterwards, makes sense, holding the reference you can mutate its state.

Answer (score 1):

`Single()` is a method that returns a value. You can't usually *assign* to the return from an expression. It is ultimately no different to saying:

```cs
Math.Max(32, 42) = 14;
```

at which point, `Max` is going to say "um, no; I was telling *you* the answer - I wasn't expecting you to tell me".

---

In theory, what you want here *is* possible, but only in advanced scenarios involving `ref`-returns. LINQ does not deal with `ref`-returns.

Answer (score 0):

Will below linq address your requirement?

```
      items.Where(i => i.Code== line.code)?.ToList()?.ForEach(i => i.name= line.name);
```

Comment: No there are a lot of properties to change in one single object and I thought it would be better to directly give the new object than doing a lot of times the Linq query,
Thank you for your answer though

Comment: @RyanL then we can use like, items.Where(i => i.Code== line.code)?.ToList()?.ForEach(i => i = line)     right?